# Huge Node/NPM crash in long-time used front-end project framework

Tags: node.js, xcode, npm, gulp, fsevents

I have a Npm Gulp framework that has been used for well over a year now, however, since running some updates this week, every project that uses it no longer runs any of my gulp commands.

I have tried updating global gulp, checked version of Node (v10.6.0) and NPM (6.1.0) and spent the last few hours on StackOverflow and other online resources but a lot of proposed solutions have been tried and failed.

Xcode is installed, Command Line Tools is installed.

I am baffled as to what could have kicked this off, I'm not expecting a solution, but a point in the right direction would be tremendously helpful.

Here's my trace once I run `npm i`.

```
> fsevents@1.1.2 install /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404):     https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.2 and node@10.6.0 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back     to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined):     https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.2/fse-v1.1.2-node-v64-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.2 and node@10.6.0 (node-v64 ABI) (falling back     to source compile with node-gyp)
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory     '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory     '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory     '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory     '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
In file included from In file included from ../fsevents.cc../fsevents.cc::66:
:
In file included from In file included from ../../nan/nan.h../../nan/nan.h::192192:
:
../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h:112../../nan/nan_maybe_43_inl.h::15112:: 15: error: error: no memberno      namedmember  'ForceSet'named  in'ForceSet'  'v8::Object'in
'v8::Object'
  return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
         ~~~  ^
  return obj->ForceSet(isolate->GetCurrentContext(), key, value, attribs);
         ~~~  ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:834:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:849:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:164:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:864:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:157:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:834:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:849:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:164:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:864:18: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return node::MakeCallback(
                 ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:157:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deIn file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:1473:31: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return scope.Escape(node::MakeCallback(
                              ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
precated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:6:
../../nan/nan.h:1473:31: warning: 'MakeCallback' is deprecated: Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)     [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    return scope.Escape(node::MakeCallback(
                              ^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:171:1: note: 'MakeCallback' has been explicitly marked     deprecated here
NODE_DEPRECATED("Use MakeCallback(..., async_context)",
^
/Users/<user>/.node-gyp/10.6.0/include/node/node.h:88:20: note: expanded from macro 'NODE_DEPRECATED'
    __attribute__((deprecated(message))) declarator
                   ^
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
4 warnings and 1 error generated.
make: make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1*** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1

gypgyp  ERR!ERR!  build errorbuild error

gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp gypERR!  ERR!stack      at ChildProcess.onExit     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
stackgyp Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
stackgyp     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
 gypERR!  ERR!stack      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! Systemgyp Darwin 16.7.0
 ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.6.0/bin/node"     "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build"     "--module=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.    node" "--module_name=fse"     "--module_path=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
gypgyp  ERR! ERR!command  "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.6.0/bin/node"     "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build"     "--module=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.    node" "--module_name=fse"     "--module_path=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64"
cwd /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents
gyp gyp ERR! ERR!cwd  /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents
node -v v10.6.0
gyp gypERR!  ERR!node -v  v10.6.0
node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp gypERR!  ERR!node-gyp -v  v3.6.2
not ok
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.6.0/bin/node     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build     --module=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.    node --module_name=fse     --module_path=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64'     (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>     (/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.6.0/bin/node"     "/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install"     "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.36
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.6.0/bin/node     /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build     --module=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64/fse.    node --module_name=fse     --module_path=/Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v64-darwin-x64'     (1)

> uws@9.14.0 install /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0


> node-sass@4.9.0 install /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/darwin-x64-64_binding.node
Download complete  ⸩ ⠋ :
Binary saved to /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-64/binding.node
Caching binary to /Users/<user>/.npm/node-sass/4.9.0/darwin-x64-64_binding.node

> nunjucks@3.1.3 postinstall /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/nunjucks
> node postinstall-build.js src


> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-64/binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ gifsicle pre-build test passed successfully

> jpegtran-bin@3.2.0 postinstall /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/jpegtran-bin
> node lib/install.js

  ✔ jpegtran pre-build test passed successfully

> optipng-bin@3.1.4 postinstall /Users/<user>/Development/<project>/node_modules/optipng-bin
> node lib/install.js

(node:83110) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners     added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
  ✔ optipng pre-build test passed successfully
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.2 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

added 2185 packages from 1381 contributors and audited 21717 packages in 48.208s
found 265 vulnerabilities (206 low, 31 moderate, 28 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was broken where, but to resolve this, I had to point the `xcode-select` developer directory to the right place with `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Then I uninstalled and reinstalled the fsevents package. I realised this error mostly occurred from my attempt to fix the `found 265 vulnerabilities` noted at the bottom of the trace above.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your fsevents version in your package.json, that version seems to not support the version of Node.js that you are running (version 10).

Your best bet is to either downgrade your node version, or update your fsevents package to the latest version (1.2.4)

Good luck!

Comment: I forgot to come back and reply to myself, but thanks very much for your time, Stephen . See answer below 